# Unable to send emails through an Outlook add-in due to Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, content-security-policy, outlook-web-addins

I manage an Office Add-in that helps aids in user productivity when writing emails. Part of the functionality of this plugin also includes adding content to the body of the emails. However, the source of the content is external which seems to trigger the content security policy set by Microsoft and prevents the email from being sent. Here is what the error I get when looking at DevTools console:

[Error in DevTools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Z9G.png)

However, the same add-in works as expected in the Outlook for Mac client. Additionally, despite the content (such as images) being blocked, it is still being rendered in the compose window normally.

I've also noticed this intermittent error when it comes to CSP which I'm unsure if it is related or not:

[Intermitted Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1AEq.png)

Upon further debugging into the callstack where the CSP error is thrown, it appears to fail in event handler for the Outlook editor.

[Outlook editor source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7jES.png)

Has anyone run into this and if so, any tips on how to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

I've tried various Outlook office accounts including personal and Office 365 accounts and both experience the same issue of not being to send emails, though the exact behavior and scenarios vary a bit.

The error also does not appear to bubble up to the add-in code where try-catching would not be able to workaround this issue.

This appears to be a very recent issue since this was working fine before Feb 8.

Comment: What line of code causes such errors in your add-in? Do you try to fetch anything from an external URL?

Answer (score 0):

Because Office Add-ins are webpages that run in a web browser control, they must follow the same-origin policy enforced by the browser. Read more about security in web add-ins in the [Privacy and security for Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/privacy-and-security) article.

Also you may find the [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) page helpful.